# Is it possible to have user input come from a form input in this Stripe example?

Tags: javascript, npm, stripe-payments

Is it possible to modify this Stripe example so as to have the user input an amount in a text box. I am able to alter the amount on the server.js file and i know how to get the form working in the checkout.html but I don't know how to send the value forward when the button is clicked to that server.js can get it.

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder

---

**server.js**

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: 'Stubborn Attachments',
            images: ['https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png'],
          },
          unit_amount: 2000,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
  });
```

---

**checkout.html**

Answer (score 0):

You can, you just have to capture the amount in a form and then POST that data to your server before creating the Checkout Session.

For example:

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const amount = parseInt(req.body.amount, 10) * 100;

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: 'Stubborn Attachments',
            images: ['https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png'],
          },
          unit_amount: amount,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
  });

  res.json(session.id);
});
```

Here's an example of how to do this in Glitch:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stripe-checkout-donate

End result looks like this:

https://stripe-checkout-donate.glitch.me/